# Double wrapping Fibonacci

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I try to use two different wrappers on a recursive Fibonacci function to: 1) Count the number of recursions, 2) Memoize the computed values to reduce computations needed.

As each wrapping function creates a new function attribute on the created function, after wrapping again I can't access it anymore.
Is there a way to still access it without doing a single wrap function with both effects ?

```
def count(f):
    def f1(*args):
        f1.counter += 1
        return f(*args)
    f1.counter = 0
    return f1

def memoize(f):
    def f1(*args):
        if not args in f1.memo:
            f1.memo[args] = f(*args)
        return f1.memo[args]
    f1.memo = {}
    return f1

@memoize
@count
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
```

After this I can access fib.memo but not fib.counter, and conversely if I wrap fib with memoize before count.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was originally closed as a duplicate to [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-to-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators), where it is correctly pointed out that using `functools.wraps` to chain decorators can help by copying all the attributes of the wrapped function to the wrapper function.

However, I'm reopening this question because using `functools.wraps` won't completely work in your case due to your `counter` attribute being an immutable integer, so having `wraps` copy the `counter` attribute to the wrapper actually only copies its initial value of 0 to the wrapper, and subsequent changes to the `counter` attribute of the wrapped function won't be reflected in the wrapper's `counter` attribute, which is why:

```
from functools import wraps

def count(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def f1(*args):
        f1.counter += 1
        return f(*args)
    f1.counter = 0
    return f1

def memoize(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def f1(*args):
        if not args in f1.memo:
            f1.memo[args] = f(*args)
        return f1.memo[args]
    f1.memo = {}
    return f1

@memoize
@count
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)

print(fib(4))
print(fib.memo)
print(fib.counter)
```

incorrectly outputs:

```
3
{(1,): 1, (0,): 0, (2,): 1, (3,): 2, (4,): 3}
0
```

To remedy this, you have to initialize `counter` with a mutable object. Since Python does not have a mutable integer natively, you can create a custom class that wraps around an integer instead:

```
class Int:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.value = value

def count(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def f1(*args):
        f1.counter.value += 1
        return f(*args)
    f1.counter = Int()
    return f1
```

so that:

```
print(fib(4))
print(fib.memo)
print(fib.counter.value)
```

would correctly output:

```
3
{(1,): 1, (0,): 0, (2,): 1, (3,): 2, (4,): 3}
5
```